# window.open issue in IE9, opens new window with 4px overhead on dimension specified

Tags: html, internet-explorer, window.open, frameset

I am having this weird issue with window.open in IE. It creates new window with extra width & height than I had specified.

```
popped_window = window.open('http://localhost/window/window-width.php','_blank','width=800,height=600,scrollbars=no')
```

The code above opens a IE window with 804px and 604px (innerWidth, innnerWidth). Outer Height differs with features I have selected (address bar, status bar etc.). Its natural but why the inner dimensions has to change by 4px.

Somewhere it was written that this additional 4px on both dimensions are for scrollbars. IE puts it to make sure that width remains same if the content on the window adds up the scroll bar or not. I don't have MSDN article to prove it, since I saw that in some forum.

Also this behavior of 4px addition doesn't show up if new window opened has  on its content. This is the real trouble maker as frameset may appear/dissapear dynamically on the new window.

I already tried window.resizeTo(), which didn't help at all. Nothing I could find on stackoverflow. So any Suggestions?

Comment: Popups with specified dimensions are dead – we are living in the times of tabbed browsing, so you as a web site author have less and less control over how big a window actually is. In my browser f.e. window.open will _always_ open a new tab with the same size as all other tabs – regardless of what anyone might have specified as desired dimensions. Instead of worrying about a 4px difference, I’d rather invest my time in making the content look good at any possible window/tab size.

Comment: agreed; but this app i was talking about is large scale app (so called "Big ball of mud") http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud so i have to stick with it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occured in Standard Mode, I shifted to Quirks and its working for now.